# SwitchPreference in pre Android 7 always switched off

Tags: android, xml, switchpreference

I'm extending `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, in the `onCreatePreferences` method the preference are set using `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)`.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="disableAppWhenObscured"
        android:title="@string/screen_settings_block_app_when_obscured" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

As dependency I have the following entry:

```
implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.0.0"
```

On devices post Android 6.X, everything works like expected. On devices with Android 6 and pre-6, the switches are always off and not changeable if clicked on it, even not changeable programmatically but the change listener gets fired.

You know what the problem is?

Edit: If I change the UI element to `CheckBoxPreference`, everything works as expected even in Android 6 and pre-6. Furthermore before I started using `androidX` the `SwitchPreference` worked as well.

Edit2: Found out that the `switchView` is `null` inside the `SwitchPreference` in the following method:

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
    View switchView = holder.findViewById(AndroidResources.ANDROID_R_SWITCH_WIDGET);
    syncSwitchView(switchView);
    syncSummaryView(holder);
}
```

and this leads to not changeing the UI in the `syncSwitchView` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [SwitchPreferenceCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/SwitchPreferenceCompat) instead of SwitchPreference should resolve the problem.